# Merging time series

Tags: haskell

Is there a better way to do this?

A time series,

```
data Model a where
  Variant  :: [(Day, a)] -> Model a
  deriving (Show)
```

... where type `a` in `[(Day, a)]` basically represents the "total balance" e.g. bank account.

Some example data,

```
day1 = fromGregorian 1987 10 17
day2 = fromGregorian 1987 10 18
day3 = fromGregorian 1987 10 19
day4 = fromGregorian 1987 10 20
day5 = fromGregorian 1987 10 21
day6 = fromGregorian 1987 10 22

m1 = Variant [(day1, 1), (day3, 3), (day5, 5)] :: Model Integer
m2 = Variant [(day1, 1), (day2, 2), (day4, 4), (day6, 6)] :: Model Integer
```

Now, merge two time series such that the "total balance" is additive,

```
(&+) :: Num a => Model a -> Model a -> Model a
(Variant a) &+ (Variant b) = Variant $ reverse $ fst $ go a b ([],0)
  where
    go             []             [] (xs, c) = (xs, c)
    go   ((da,va):as)             [] (xs, c) = go as [] (((da,va+c):xs), va+c)
    go             []   ((db,vb):bs) (xs, c) = go [] bs (((db,vb+c):xs), vb+c)
    go a@((da,va):as) b@((db,vb):bs) (xs, c)
      | da > db  = go  a bs (((db,vb+c):xs), vb+c)
      | da < db  = go as  b (((da,va+c):xs), va+c)
      | da == db = go as bs (((da,va+vb+c):xs), va+vb+c)
```

So,

```
what = m1 &+ m2

Variant [(1987-10-17,2),(1987-10-18,4),(1987-10-19,7),(1987-10-20,11),(1987-10-21,16),(1987-10-22,22)]
```

Now, I believe `(&+)` to be correct, but I have a feeling that the implementation could be more elegant.  I would describe it as merging two lists of pairs where the `snd` is accumulated.  Is there a better way to implement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is you are doing two things at once: merging the two day lists, and calculating an accumulation of a list. Note that I'm going to assume the Variant is always in order, as it will make everything much more efficient.

Firstly, to join two variants, I used this:

```
(Variant v1) `concatModels` (Variant v2) = Variant $ joinVariants v1 v2 where
  joinVariants x [] = x
  joinVariants [] y = y
  joinVariants (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | (fst x < fst y) = x : joinVariants xs (y:ys)
    | (fst x == fst y) = (fst x, (snd x) + (snd y)) : joinVariants xs ys
    | otherwise = y : joinVariants (x:xs) ys
```

This is pretty straightforward. If either list is empty, the result is the other. Otherwise, check the first value of each list. Put the value with the oldest date (`fst x`) first. If they are equal, combine the values by adding them together.

Next, it is trivial to make `Model` an instance of Functor, Foldable, and Traversable. So trivial in fact that haskell can generate the code itself:

```
deriving (Show, Eq, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

With Traverable, we have access to the function `mapAccumL`, which will let us map over the `Model` using an accumulator to update. this makes the problem simple to solve:

```
modelAccumulation  :: Num a => Model a -> Model a         
modelAccumulation = snd . mapAccumL accumF 0 where
  accumF acc v = let newAcc = acc + v in (newAcc, newAcc)


(&+) :: Num a => Model a -> Model a -> Model a
m1 &+ m2 = modelAccumulation $ concatModels m1 m2
```

This gives the same answer as your old code. Full listing:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module Main where
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Data.Function
import Data.Traversable
import Data.Foldable

data Model a = Variant [(Day, a)]
  deriving (Show, Eq, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

(Variant v1) `concatModels` (Variant v2) = Variant $ joinVariants v1 v2 where
  joinVariants x [] = x
  joinVariants [] y = y
  joinVariants (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | (fst x < fst y) = x : joinVariants xs (y:ys)
    | (fst x == fst y) = (fst x, (snd x) + (snd y)) : joinVariants xs ys
    | otherwise = y : joinVariants (x:xs) ys

modelAccumulation  :: Num a => Model a -> Model a         
modelAccumulation = snd . mapAccumL accumF 0 where
  accumF acc v = let newAcc = acc + v in (newAcc, newAcc)


(&+) :: Num a => Model a -> Model a -> Model a
m1 &+ m2 = modelAccumulation $ concatModels m1 m2


day1 = fromGregorian 1987 10 17
day2 = fromGregorian 1987 10 18
day3 = fromGregorian 1987 10 19
day4 = fromGregorian 1987 10 20
day5 = fromGregorian 1987 10 21
day6 = fromGregorian 1987 10 22

m1 = Variant [(day1, 1), (day3, 3), (day5, 5)] :: Model Integer
m2 = Variant [(day1, 1), (day2, 2), (day4, 4), (day6, 6)] :: Model Integer


what = m1 &+ m2

expected = Variant [(fromGregorian 1987 10 17,2),(fromGregorian 1987 10 18,4),(fromGregorian 1987 10 19,7),(fromGregorian 1987 10 20,11),(fromGregorian 1987 10 21,16),(fromGregorian 1987 10 22,22)]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts: first, you need to merge two lists with `(+)`, second, you need to traverse the resulting list and accumulate values.

```
(Variant a) &+ (Variant b) =
    Variant $ snd $ mapAccumL (\r (d, k) -> let r' = r + k in (r', (d, r'))) 0
        $ toList $ Map.unionWith (+)
            (Map.fromDistinctAscList a)
            (Map.fromDistinctAscList b)
```

This is still O(n), since all involved functions are O(n).
The whole code: http://ideone.com/Z9Os4c

Comment: This would be a great answer on SO, but unfortunately, fails to give a proper code review. (For example, you could also address the poor variable names that OP is using as well.)

Comment: I answered this question: "Is there a better way to implement?" So my answer is illegal, only if the question is illegal, but I don't think it is.

Comment: It's not an illegal answer, it's just not a very good one. I'm just trying to help you. See ya around.